# How to use Logback directly without going through SLF4J

Tags: java, testing, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm trying to tweak some logback functionality (custom Appenders and the like). In order to test it I would like to configure Logback and call its logging methods directly without going through sl4j.

The reason for this weird requirement is to be able to test logback functionality in an environment where also other SLF4J bridges are available.

So I want to do the stuff described when [invoking JoranConfigurator directly](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#joranDirectly) without a reference to SLF4J.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to find out.

Here's the example how you can configure LOGBack

```
// Here we create context
LoggerContext loggerContext = new LoggerContext();
// Initializer is used to enrich context with details
ContextInitializer contextInitializer = new ContextInitializer(loggerContext);
try {
    // Get a configuration file from classpath
    URL configurationUrl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("custom-logback-configuration.xml");
    if (configurationUrl == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to find custom logback configuration file");
    }
    // Ask context initializer to load configuration into context
    contextInitializer.configureByResource(configurationUrl);
    // Here we get logger from context
    logger = loggerContext.getLogger(LogReporter.class);
} catch (JoranException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to configure logger", e);
}
```

In general if you want to know how any SLF4J backend works, you may just to look at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder class source from that backend.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in a similar context where I needed to set up a Logback 'environment' (context) explicitly without relying on the SLF4J binding (since SLF4J was already bound to log4j and I didn't have access to the classpath to be able to change it by using the various SLF4J bridges or similar).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, I don't think its possible. If you take a look at the [Logback Logger source](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.java) (or other classes) you will see it depends on slf4j.

This is not nice, imho, as logback should be unaware of slf4j.

Comment: Actually, it may not DEPEND on slf4j. It may just be a static binding to the slf4j interface. `NATIVE IMPLEMENTATION There are also SLF4J bindings external to the SLF4J project, e.g. logback which implements SLF4J natively. Logback's ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger class is a direct implementation of SLF4J's org.slf4j.Logger interface. Thus, using SLF4J in conjunction with logback involves strictly zero memory and computational overhead.` https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but looks correct, maybe it will help:

```
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger log = lc.getLogger(foo.Bar.class);
```

The `ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger` implements `org.slf4j.Logger` but you can use it directly. You might need to obtain `LoggerContext` differently.

Comment: LoggerFactory is part of slf4j and useses the class StaticLoggerBinder which comes with the various bridge implementations so I'm still using the binding mechanism of slf4j with this.

Comment: @JensSchauder: what about simply creating `new LoggerContext()` and avoiding SLF4J API completely?

Comment: I am developing an API, where I can not use SLF4j at all, is it possible to use logback standalone ?

Comment: `LoggerContext logCtx = new LoggerContext();` worked for me. Why does java have to make logging a living hell?!